# Google Api not giving response in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api

I want to get the response in a string `responseString`. But when I debug my code it does not work and after some time it gives me error as.

> The operation has timed out

Below is the code

```
string url = String.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input={0}&key={1}", "Andheri West".Replace(" ", ","), "AIzaSyA5WiXTvjPSXEMGwFP0olr9vQuHSk-GVjY");
            WebClient Webclient = new WebClient();
            WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            Uri featureUri = new Uri(url);
            string responseString = Webclient.UploadString(featureUri, "POST", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are applying `POST` request but it is wrong. You should apply `GET` request. So you could use `Webclient.DownloadString`

```
string url = String.Format("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input={0}&key={1}", "Andheri West".Replace(" ", ","), "AIzaSyA5WiXTvjPSXEMGwFP0olr9vQuHSk-GVjY");
WebClient Webclient = new WebClient();
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
Uri featureUri = new Uri(url);
string responseString = Webclient.DownloadString(featureUri);
```

Also, don't share your key with us.

**EDIT**

Obviously, it seems that your environment requires proxy configuration and you can configure the proxy settings in config file for your application. It looks like;

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy proxyaddress="proxyAddress" usesystemdefault="True"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: does it take bydefault as `GET` ?

Comment: it is the natural behaviour of "DownloadString".

Comment: I have just tested it. It should be a problem with your google access.

Comment: what type of access ? sorry didnt got you. what response did you got ?

Comment: Would you try to access to url https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Andheri,West&key=AIzaSyA5WiXTvjPSXEMGwFP0olr9vQuHSk-GVjY with your browser ?

Comment: yes, it works and i get something like this `{
   "predictions" : [
      {
         "description" : "Andheri West, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India",
         "id" : "f281b96e246e3cc8f79f6d65abbf04b8b05aa08d",
         "matched_substrings" : [
            {
               "length" : 12,
               "offset" : 0
            }`....

Comment: Do you have a proxy configuration in your application ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163409/discussion-between-vvvv-and-stormcloak).